# How to open menu hyperlink in a new tab instead of new window?

Tags: jquery

How to open menu hyperlink in a new tab instead of new window?

In this case below is my code and its currently opening in new windows not same browser tab.

```
_bindEventsMain:function(){
  $('.menu-link').on('click', HomeJs._menuClick);
}    

_menuClick:function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var t = $(this).attr('data-title');
    var popup = window.open(href,t, '_blank');
},
```

Comment: It's a browser preference Debabrat, cannot be manipulated with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `_blank` in second argument.

```
var popup = window.open(href, '_blank');
```

Comment: @A.Wolff here it is given second.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: This will open a new window OR tab based upon the preferences of the browser

Comment: Nice works like a charm